# I don't get how this code puts a integer and a comma after a variable when it's calling the variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start
    if start > stop:
        return_string = "Counting down: "
        while x >= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            if x != stop:
                return_string += ","
            x -= 1
    else:
        return_string = "Counting up: "
        while x <= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            if stop != x :
                return_string += ","
            x += 1
    return return_string

print(counter(1, 10)) # Should be "Counting up: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
print(counter(2, 1)) # Should be "Counting down: 2,1"
print(counter(5, 5)) # Should be "Counting up: 5"
```

So in the if statement, return_string is "Counting down: ". I don't get how it adds strings with return_string += str(x). Wouldn't it say "Counting down: " for every single string? Can someone please explain the return_string variable to me.

Comment: What do you believe `return_string += ","` is doing?

Comment: Try using a step-by-step debugger and follow the value of `return_string`

Comment: Pay close attention to the first if...else statement. That first if...else statement determines the start of the text to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

The `return_string = "Counting down: "` is being set outside the loop.
Then, for each element in the array, the element and the comma are appended the the `return_string`. The comma is not added when the last element in the array is reached.

If you move the `return_string = "Counting down: "` one line lower, basically inside the loop, you will then get an output that would look like this:

```
print(counter(2, 1)) # "Counting down: 2, Counting down: 1"
```